# How can I delete the current line in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

What is the emacs equivalent of vi's <kbd>dd</kbd>? I want to delete the current line. Tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> but it only deletes *from* current position.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

```
C-a # Go to beginning of line
C-k # Kill line from current point
```

There is also

```
C-S-backspace   # Ctrl-Shift-Backspace
```

which invokes `M-x kill-whole-line`.

If you'd like to set a different global key binding, you'd put this in ~/.emacs:

```
(global-set-key "\C-cd" 'kill-whole-line)     # Sets `C-c d` to `M-x kill-whole-line`
```

---

If you want to delete a number of whole lines, you can prefix the command with a number:

```
C-u 5 C-S-backspace    # deletes 5 whole lines
M-5 C-S-backspace      # deletes 5 whole lines

C-u C-S-backspace      # delete 4 whole lines. C-u without a number defaults to 4

C-u -5 C-S-backspace   # deletes previous 5 whole lines
M--5 C-S-backspace     # deletes previous 5 whole lines
```

Sometimes I also find `C-x z` helpful:

```
C-S-backspace         # delete 1 whole line
C-x z                 # repeat last command
z                     # repeat last command again. 
                      # Press z as many times as you wish. 
                      # Any other key acts normally, and ends the repeat command.
```

Comment: This works. Is there a way to do this using one command? Will I have to create a custom key binding to do this?

Comment: Didn't know `C-x z`, that's really cool. And nice and precise answer btw.

Comment: There's also `C-k C-k` which kinda works like a `d$ S-j` in vim, but this can delete lines forward fairly nicely.

Comment: Why isn't there a space in `C-cd`?

Comment: @RenéG: The space is optional.

Comment: You can also consider `smart-kill-whole-line` that takes care of indentation: http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/09/kill-whole-line/

Answer (score 11):

In case you don't want to kill the line (which would put it into the OS clipboard and kill ring) but simply delete it:

```
(defun delete-current-line ()
  "Delete (not kill) the current line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (delete-region
     (progn (forward-visible-line 0) (point))
     (progn (forward-visible-line 1) (point)))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another method to delete the line without placing it into the kill ring:

```
(defun delete-current-line ()
  "Deletes the current line"
  (interactive)
  (delete-region
   (line-beginning-position)
   (line-end-position)))
```

This will leave the point at the beginning of a blank line. To get rid of this also, you may wish to add something like `(delete-blank-lines)` to the end of the function, as in this example, which is perhaps a little less intuitive:

```
(defun delete-current-line ()
 "Deletes the current line"
 (interactive)
 (forward-line 0)
 (delete-char (- (line-end-position) (point)))
 (delete-blank-lines))
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than having separate key to delete line, or having to invoke
prefix-argument. You can use [crux-smart-kill-line](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux/blob/308f17d914e2cd79cbc809de66d02b03ceb82859/crux.el#L199)
which will "kill to the end of the line and kill whole line on the next
call". But if you prefer `delete` instead of `kill`, you can use the
code below.

For point-to-string operation (kill/delete) I recommend to use [zop-to-char](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/zop-to-char)

```lisp
(defun aza-delete-line ()
  "Delete from current position to end of line without pushing to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (line-end-position)))

(defun aza-delete-whole-line ()
  "Delete whole line without pushing to kill-ring."
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))

(defun crux-smart-delete-line ()
  "Kill to the end of the line and kill whole line on the next call."
  (interactive)
  (let ((orig-point (point)))
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (if (= orig-point (point))
        (aza-delete-whole-line)
      (goto-char orig-point)
      (aza-delete-line))))
```

[source](https://github.com/azzamsa/scripts.el#smart-delete-line)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest/simplest way to delete (kill) a full line, from any point
on the line, without selecting anything, is:

```
C-w  ; kill-region
```

It is versatile in deleting whatever is selected, or a line by default
if nothing is selected.

Given the question, you're probably also interested in replicating
Vim's "yank", `yy` (though in Emacs parlance a "yank" is confusingly
Vim's "put", `p`).  This is:

```
M-w  ; kill-ring-save
```

Nice and congruent, and pretty easy to remember.  Even slightly
similar to Vim's `i_CTRL-W`.

Once you've put something in the kill ring with either of the above,
you'll likely want to "yank" (paste) it:

```
M-y  ; yank-pop
```

*(Note that C-S-backspace may not work in terminal Emacs.)*

Answer (score 0):

Install package `whole-line-or-region` and then run `(whole-line-or-region-global-mode)`.  This will make `C-w` kill the whole line if no region (selection) is active.

See the Package's GitHub page https://github.com/purcell/whole-line-or-region