# C-k to remove a line but when the cursor is located at the end of the line

Tags: emacs

In emacs 24, is there a **built-in** hotkey to destroy a line when the cursor is located at the end of the line without having to move it at the beginning of the line? C-k works only when the cursor is at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ctrl-Shift-backspace` removes the whole line, wherever the cursor is.

It does not appear to work in xterm, but works with Gtk front-end.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Killing-by-Lines.html

[How can I delete the current line in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958528/how-can-i-delete-the-current-line-in-emacs)

Comment: is it 4 keys pressed at the same time?

Comment: is it 4 keys pressed at the same time?

Comment: 3 keys (ctrl shift Backspace), at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `C-S-backspace` (`kill-whole-line`) as jamieguinan mentions, you can give `kill-line` a prefix argument of 0 (i.e., type `C-0 C-k`) to kill the portion of the line preceding point.